# Supporting two URI's with same servlet

Tags: java, web-services, http, servlets, web

Currently we have all links on our site set up as `/xxx/UseCase`.

We would like to now accept incoming requests with the prefix `/yyy` such as `/yyy/xxx/UseCase`.  So we would have one servlet that accepts requests on both `/yyy/xxx/UseCase` and `/xxx/UseCase`.

How can we do this?

Biggest challenge here being: A number of pages redirect to other URI's using the absolute path.  Ie: the `Patients` servlet redirects to `/xxx/Insurance`.  Issue is if you're at `/yyy/xxx/Patients` you shouldn't now get redirected to `/xxx/Insurance` - you should get redirected to `/yyy/xxx/Insurance`

Answer (score 4):

You can just map a servlet on more than one URL pattern:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fooServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxx/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/yyy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or when you're already on Servlet 3.0:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/xxx/*", "/yyy/*"})
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

You can if necessary use `/yyy/xxx/*` instead of `/yyy/*`.

Or if you intend to untouch the servlet mapping, you could also create a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which forwards requests on `/yyy/xxx/*` to `/xxx/*`. Something like this (basic checks omitted):

```
@WebFilter("/yyy/xxx/*")
public class FooFilter implements Filter {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String oldURI = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length() + 1);
        String newURI = oldURI.substring(oldURI.indexOf("/"));
        req.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you intend to change the URL in the browser address bar from `/yyy/xxx/*` to `/xxx/*`, then you need to use [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29):

```
         // ...
         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         res.sendRedirect(newURI);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The challenge is more connected to the redirects as described in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the concrete problem is and how exactly that's a problem (or "challenge" as you call it). In general, a `Filter` is to be used to modify requests/responses. There exist even 3rd party ones such as Tuckey's URLRewriteFilter which is much like the well known HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`: http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/ This is however completely unrelated to the initial question as to how to map a single servlet on multiple URL patterns.

Comment: I've updated an answer with a filter example of which I think it would solve your concrete problem ("challenge").

Comment: Thanks, good ideas.  These would help with mapping the two URI's to a given Servlet/REST API.  The issue I was referring to is if a given servlet is accessed via `/yyy/xxx/UseCase`, currently we have some hard coded redirects to `/xxx/AnotherUseCase`.  We don't want this - we don't want someone on `/yyy/xxx` to be redirected to a `/xxx/` URI.  @Dave's answer below is a suggestion on how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with your servlet mapping.  I think it is with how you're doing your redirects.  Try this for your redirect logic...

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI().replace("Patients", "Insurance"));
```

This way you don't have to mess with if statements as it should work in both situations.

Comment: This is a good suggestion although it means we'd have to change a fair bit of code/HTML to change how we generate links.  Was hoping for a solution that might involve less work.

Comment: I'm a little confused because if this is just a server side redirect I don't see what the html would have to do with out it gets redirected on the server side. How are you generating your links?

Comment: I've never used JSP.  I've gone templates route; but I'm guessing your mixing your views and controllers.  I can't judge; I think a lot of people have done that before but it can lead to nightmares.  Constructive criticism aside if you really feel you need a hack/quick fix then you're probably going to have to write a servlet filter which intercepts all outgoing responses and makes sure they're being redirected to the proper url based on their request.  This is a hack though and you should attempt to refactor and encapsulate the logic which does this into a central location if possible.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know if it is possible to redirect a response once its already been set; so I'm not going to include that as part of my answer.....